# How to get position in rotated VisualTree?

Tags: wpf, canvas, tree, element, rotation

I have canvas inside the canvas and other elements inside canvas father.
But my grandfather canvas is rotated.

How I get real position in childrens (relative do grandFather)?

## Fail:

```
VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(controlClicked)
canvasGrandFather.TranslatePoint(new Point(), controlClicked)
Canvas.GetTop and Canvas.GetLeft
```

[image]

I have to take the position of the green square, for the background image.
Each contour / border is a Canvas

Basically I have:
Image 
Canvas 
--GrandFatherCanvas 
----FatherCanvas 
------ChildrenCanvas 
I need ChildrenCanvas position in relation to the 1st Canvas. Sorry my english is bad..

Comment: Do you possibly mean the position of children relative to the parent container of `canvasGrandFather`? Everything contained in a rotated Canvas is also rotated, so relative positions are not aware of any rotation.

Comment: What is the background image? Do you mean the positions of the green rectangles relative to the canvas with red border?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know if I can explain the situation, I updated the question.

Comment: Then you should use `firstCanvas.TranslatePoint` instead of `grandFatherCanvas.TranslatePoint`.

Comment: I love your naming convention!

Comment: Do you want the relative position of the canvas after its rotated? Or do you want the relative position as if it was never rotated even though it appears rotated?

Answer (score 0):

Assume your 1st canvas is called `firstCanvas`, you should be able to do this:

```
Point p = firstCanvas.TranslatePoint(new Point(), controlClicked);
```

Or you go via [TransformToAncestor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608865.aspx):

```
GeneralTransform t = controlClicked.TransformToAncestor(firstCanvas);
Point p = t.Transform(new Point());
```

Comment: As I said, there may exist rotation  in any component, it imposibilita the value returned is the real value of position.

Comment: Ok, then you have to get the transform from the canvas (or all transforms from all canvases) and use that for your calculations.

Comment: but do not know exactly what to do and how to do = /